# Trying to get subdomain URL using php

Tags: php, url, subdomain

Actually I am trying to get the sub-domain URL using php. I write code below:

```
$sub_url = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$suburl = $sub_url[0];
```

For Example:
if sub domain URL is like `my.example.com`
the code above is giving me `my` which is good but if there is no sub domain then my code will return `example` which is not good.

I want anything before the first dot even `www` but if there is nothing like if URL is `example.com` then I want a blank value instead of `example`.

Comment: `if (count($sub_url) > 2)` ?  Keep in mind, `one.two.three.domain.com` could also occur.

Comment: Great point and I have done that using the way you said.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a one-liner to get the subdomain:

```
$subdomain = join('.', explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], -2))
```

`explode` with the limit parameter of `-2` will split the string on each dot, ignoring the last two elements. If there are two or fewer elements, it returns an empty array.

`join` will assemble the resulting array back into a dot delimited string. In case you have multiple subdomains set, e.g. `foo.bar.domain.com` will return `foo.bar`.

If there is no subdomain, it will return an empty string.

Comment: Worked for me if I change the parameter to: 1

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume you can just check the size of the array, assuming it was always the same size, if it was any larger you may run into problems.

```
$sub_url = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

if (sizeof($sub_url) > 2) {
    $suburl = $sub_url[0];
} else {
    $suburl = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that, there are also websites with second level domains, for example `co.uk`, `com.cn`. If you can make sure, that your code will not be used on such website, you can simple use the answer of `DarthJDG` or check `count($sub_url) > 2`. But if not, you need to check the domain name.

```
$secondLevelDomainsList = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('https://raw.github.com/gavingmiller/second-level-domains/master/SLDs.csv'), PHP_EOL);
foreach($secondLevelDomainsList as &$item) {
    list($tld, $stld) = str_getcsv($item, ",");
    $item = $stld;
}    
$urlParts = explode('.', $url);    
$challenger = '.' . join('.', array_slice($urlParts, -2, 2, true));    
$length = in_array($challenger, $secondLevelDomainsList) ? -3 : -2;    
$subDomainName = join('.', array_slice($urlParts, 0, $length, true));
```

The list of second level domains in format of CSV from [gavingmiller/second-level-domains](https://github.com/gavingmiller/second-level-domains) github repository is used for the test, if the domain is a second level domain.

Comment: And using any list like that gives you two problems: what happens if you can not access it for whatever reason, and how can you be sure it is up to date (last commit there was 4 years ago). Here is another one kept more up to date because used by all browsers: https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat  (read https://publicsuffix.org/ for explanations on what is it and how it is used).

Comment: Yes, there will be such problems. But to the first problem, a local copy or cache can be used. To the second, the git repository in the code is a simple example, my purpose is to notice, that the second level domain should also be considered.